# Pine Script v5 - Strategy doesnt show any data?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am writing a strategy with pine script v5:
strategy.entry when both MACD , KDJ and SAR crossover
strategy.exit when the price reach ATR value *2 (-ATR value *2 = cut loss /  +ATR value *2  = Take profit)

but there is no data (no order created) in strategy tester.

tried to debug for few rounds but no luck, appreciate if can any expert could help .

Thank you very much.

here is the code for reference:

```
//@version=5
strategy("Combined Indicator Strategy", overlay=true)
import TradingView/ta/7

// define MACD
[macdLine, signalLine, _] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
macdUpCross = macdLine > signalLine

// define KDJ
ilong = input(9, title="period")
isig = input(3, title="signal")

bcwsma(s, l, m) =>
    var float _bcwsma = na
    _bcwsma := (m * s + (l - m) * nz(_bcwsma[1])) / l
    _bcwsma

c = close
h = ta.highest(high, ilong)
l = ta.lowest(low, ilong)
RSV = 100 * ((c - l) / (h - l))
pK = bcwsma(RSV, isig, 1)
pD = bcwsma(pK, isig, 1)
pJ = 3 * pK - 2 * pD

plot(pK, color = color.new(color.blue, 0), transp = 0)
plot(pD, color = color.new(color.orange, 0), transp = 0)
plot(pJ, color = color.new(color.black, 0), transp = 0)
bgcolor(pJ > pD ? color.new(color.green, 75) : color.new(color.red, 75))
h0 = hline(80)
h1 = hline(20)

kdjUpCross = ta.crossover(pK, pD) and ta.crossover(pJ, pK)


// define SAR
start = input(0.02)
increment = input(0.02)
maximum = input(0.2, "Max Value")
out = ta.sar(start, increment, maximum)
plot(out, "ParabolicSAR", style=plot.style_cross, color=#2962FF)
sarValue = ta.sar(start, increment, maximum)
sarUpCross = ta.valuewhen(sarValue > low, sarValue, 0)


// enter
enterCondition = macdUpCross and sarUpCross and kdjUpCross
plot(enterCondition ? 1 : 0, color=color.green, title="Entry Condition")

if enterCondition
    strategy.entry("open long", strategy.long)

// exit
atrValue = ta.atr(14)

strategy.exit("Exit Long Profit", "Long", limit= strategy.position_avg_price + (atrValue * 2))
strategy.exit("Exit Short Profit", "Short", limit= strategy.position_avg_price - (atrValue * 2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exits don't work so you are stuck in a trade.

[image]

It is because you are telling `strategy.exit()` to close a position with the id `Long`. But that order id does not exist.

In your `strategy.entry()`, you set your id as `open long`. So, there is a mismatch.

Change your `strategy.entry()` to below and it will work:

```
if enterCondition
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
```

[image]